# SAS macro to loop through dataset variables and perform string matching

Tags: string, sas, sas-macro

I need to search through the 15 variables of a dataset for a specific substring (the word "None"). When I use the code below for just one variable, I can get the results I want. However, when I try to use a Macro to loop through all 15 variables, the code does not detect the word None - although there are no errors in the log.
Here is some sample data:

| ID | Var_1 | Var_2 | Var_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | None(0%) | Nearly all(100%) | None(0%) |
| 12 | Nearly all(100%) | None(0%) | None(0%) |
| 13 | None(0%) | Some (50%) | Nearly all(100%) |

SAS Code without macros (for just one variable in the dataset):

```
data countvar;
set indata;
length word $ 25;
searchstr = var_1;
** Count occurrences of substring None
None_flag=0; 
   do i=1 to countw(searchstr); 
       word=scan(searchstr,i);
       if findw("None",strip(word),'i')>=1 then do;
           None_flag=1; 
       end; 
   end; 
run;
```

Code when I use a macro to iterate through a list of variables in the dataset:

```
%macro loopit(list);
    data countvar1;
    set indata;
    %do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&list.));
        %let word  = %scan(&list., &i.);
        None_flag=0;
    
        %if %sysfunc(findw(None,strip(&word),ii))>=1 %then %do;
            None_flag=1;
        %end;
    %end;
    run;
%mend loopit;
%let list = Var_1 Var_2 Var_3 Var_4;
%loopit(list=&list)
```

The Macro code does not throw any errors - however, the variable None_flag in the output dataset is always zero.
What is going wrong, please advice. Thanks.

Comment: Answered over on communities.sas.com already.

Comment: yes, should I delete this question? Not sure what the protocol is. Thanks so much for your answer - I never when to use Arrays Vs. Macros!!!

Comment: No, please don't delete this question.  It's fair to ask a question on multiple platforms.  You'll get different answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid macros and use an array.  The issue with your macro 'solution' is that the none_flag can get reset to =0 and you are mixing scopes.

```
data have;
infile datalines dlm=',';
length id 8 var_1-var_3 $20;
input ID    Var_1   Var_2 var_3;
datalines;
11, None(0%),   Nearly all(100%),   None(0%)
12, Nearly all(100%),   None(0%),   None(0%)
13, None(0%),   Some (50%), Nearly all(100%)
;

data want;
  set have;
  array vars var_1-var_3;
  do _i_ = 1 to dim(vars) while(not none_flag);
    none_flag = findw(vars,'none',,'ip');
  end;
run;
```